# Can't import jsoup in java (not using IDE)

Tags: java, jsoup

-I am using Windows 7.

-I am not using an IDE. I am simply writing my java programs with notepad.

-I've downloaded the .jar file for jSoup library.

-I've imported the jsoup class like this: 
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
and like this
import org.jsoup.*
-I have compiled like this: javac .;jsoup.1.10.1.jar myApp.java

(I tried placing the jsoup jar file to several directories but I cant make it work)

The bug is constant, I can't import the jsoup jar: 
myApp.java:4: error: package org.jsoup does not exist
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

Any suggestions? Clearly I am missing something out.

Comment: *"(I tried placing the jsoup jar file to several directories"* such as? Were any of those directories in your [**CLASSPATH**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)?

Comment: _I am simply writing my java programs with notepad._ And you have installed Windows 7 using floppy disks??

Answer (score 2):

Put *jsoup.1.10.1.jar* to folder where your *myApp.java* file is and run this command in that folder:

```
cd folder_with_jar_and_myapp
javac -classpath jsoup.1.10.1.jar;. myApp.java
```

Answer (score 0):

set classpath like this before compile

set classpath=C:\Desktop\jars\jsoup.1.10.1.jar
then javac myApp.java

or use

javac -classpath jsoup.1.10.1.jar; myApp.java